# Take output of command as input of next command

Tags: python, input, output

If I have a python script that calls a bash script, and that bash script downloads a file to create a file, how do I take the newly created file as the input of the bash script the next time I call it.

Comment: Can you show what you have so far?  the answer probably depends on how you're issueing calls to bash -- e.g. are you using `subprocess`  (If not, you should be ;) or something else?

Comment: I'm using os.system. I can't release the code for various reasons, sorry :(

Comment: Quoting the [docs for os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system): "The [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function."

Comment: Never figured out how to use subprocess. Also, I'm an intern, and my supervisor suggested using os.system over subprocess. I'll link into subprocess though. How would I use subprocess to do what I wanted though?

Answer (score 0):

`os.system` allows for command-line redirection:

```
os.system('download-file.sh /tmp/file')  # Creates /tmp/file
os.system('read-file.sh < /tmp/file')    # reads from file
```

Comment: Or you could just pipe it directly ... `os.system('download-file.sh | read-file.sh')`

Comment: @mgilson could you explain a bit more about that code?